# useFactory provider is not being called from my module

Tags: angular

The provider for my module is not being called by Angular. I'm using Angular 14.

```
export const FIRE_BASE_AUTH = new InjectionToken<Auth>('FIRE_BASE_AUTH');

function getFirebaseAuth() {
  console.log('getFirebaseAuth called...'); // This is not showing up in the console
  return LoginSpaModule.firebaseAuth;
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: FIRE_BASE_AUTH, useFactory: getFirebaseAuth }
  ],
  exports: [LoginComponent]
})

export class LoginSpaModule {
  static firebaseAuth: Auth;
  constructor() {
    console.log('we are in the LoginSpaModule constructor...', LoginSpaModule.firebaseAuth); // This is in the console
  }
 }
```

And my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject('FIRE_BASE_AUTH') private auth: Auth,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
...
```

If I try to inject the `FIRE_BASE_AUTH` into a component, I get `NullInjectorError: No provider for FIRE_BASE_AUTH!`.  I get this also if I try other `provide` method like `useValue`.

Comment: Somehow, when I provide it as a string instead of an injection token, it works.  But I don't understand why:

`{ provide: 'FIRE_BASE_AUTH', useFactory: getFirebaseAuth }`

Comment: How are you injecting into the components? It should look something like this:
`constructor(@Inject(FIRE_BASE_AUTH) private auth: Auth) {

}`

Comment: @iProgramGUIs Yes, that is how I inject it into the component.  It only works when I provide the object as a string and not an `InjectionToken`

Comment: The string would work as the provider if its a string in the @Inject as well.  `constructor(@Inject('FIRE_BASE_AUTH')  private auth: Auth) { }`  In this case the string will bypass the token and link the string to the factory. If you use the string can you delete the token?

Comment: @iProgramGUIs Thank you so much!  I was `providing` the InjectionToken, but injecting the string.  You should post an answer and I will except it.

Comment: You're welcome Freddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string would work as the provider if its a string in the @Inject as well.
`{ provide: 'FIRE_BASE_AUTH', ... }`
`constructor(@Inject('FIRE_BASE_AUTH')  ...) { }` The token is not being used in this case.